# How to define CIDR range for ECS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

If I use ECS to run 30 container in cluster do I need to consider CIDR range that minimum allow 30 ips?

Comment: You should have more than 30 IPs as you may need vpn gateway interfaces, lambdas there or just to have a space to grow later. I would say minimum double than this if you want your subnets small,.

Comment: @Marcin will container ruining as ECS task use ip addresses, do I need to count them while sizing CIDR?

Comment: it depends on your networking mode. If you use `awsvpc` mode, then each task will have its own ip.

Answer (score -1):

A tool can be used to calculate CIDR counts: https://cidr.xyz/
To select appropriate IPs, you need to check the CIDR range of your VPC and your security group.